# == vs .equals - why different behaviour?

Tags: java, string-comparison

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

I'm sorry for this rather simple question. 
I have this very simple java program:

```
public class ArgIt {
    public static void main(String[] args){
            if(args[0].equals("x")) System.out.print("x");
            if(args[0] == "x") System.out.println("x2 ");
    }
}
```

If I call the program >java ArgIt x
it only prints a single x. 
Why will the program not acknowledge the == on the string when in any other circumstances it does?

Comment: I am expecting over four answers

Comment: Check about string interning - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_intern_pool. The second conditional fails because the two string objects are not the same, therefor the references are not the same and == returns false.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21

Comment: FYI, the link I posted above is part of the Java FAQ at the bottom of [that page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info).

Comment: @dragon66:ur desire fulfilled..more than four...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Java, you must use `equals()` for comparing equality between `String`s. `==` tests for *identity*, a different concept.

Two objects can be equal but not identical; on the other hand if two objects are identical it's implied that they're equal.

Two objects are identical if they physically point to the same address in memory, whereas two objects are equal if they have the same value, as defined by the programmer in the `equals()` method. In general, you're more interested in finding out if two objects are equal.

Comment: then for the given example which option is suitable

Comment: Strings should compare equal with equality operator? String x = "X"; x == "X" should evaluate to true.

Comment: @maress Your example happens to work as you expect.

Comment: You should use `equals()` in the general case. Only use `==` if you're interested in comparing references (memory addresses, in the end).

Answer (score 3):

`==` tests for pointer equality;`.equals` exists to test for value equality.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, comparing with the `==` operator checks for identity equality, as in the references (in the case of objects) point to the same memory location.  Because of this, only primitives should be compared using the `==` operator, as primitives (`int`, `long`, `boolean`, etc) are stored by value rather than by reference.

In short, use the `equals` method to compare objects, and the `==` operator to compare primitives.